# How do I show the delete button in my formatter ONLY if var status = 'Processing'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my formatter:

```
        formatters: {
        "commands": function (column, row) {
            return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-icon btn-primary command-edit\"  data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-target=\"#modalEdit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" data-original-title=\"Edit Sales Order\" data-placement=\"top\"><span class=\"zmdi zmdi-edit\"></span></button> " +
                "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-icon btn-danger command-delete\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-target=\"#modalDelete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" data-original-title=\"Delete Sales Order\" data-placement=\"top\"><span class=\"zmdi zmdi-delete\"></span></button> " +
                "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-icon bg-green c-white command-so\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-original-title=\"Sales Order Details\" data-placement=\"top\"><span class=\"zmdi zmdi-receipt\"></span></button> " + 
                "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-icon bg-deeporange c-white command-sorep\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-original-title=\"Accounts Receivable Report\" data-placement=\"top\"><span class=\"zmdi zmdi-chart\"></span></button>";

        }
    }
```

I only want to show the command-delete button if var status = 'Processing' for example.
The first button in the formatter is the Edit button, the second is the delete button, the third button is for a sales order report and the fourth is for a accts receivable sheet.  All work fine but I only want the delete button to show up if status = 'Processing', this will make it so that when my SO is in processing status it can still be deleted, but after its been processed and completed, no more delete button.

Thank you for your help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your `commands` callback function you could check the status and only make a delete button if necessary, e.g.

```
"commands": function (column, row) {
    var deleteButton = '';
    if (status === 'Processing') {
        deleteButton = "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-icon btn-danger command-delete\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-target=\"#modalDelete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" data-original-title=\"Delete Sales Order\" data-placement=\"top\"><span class=\"zmdi zmdi-delete\"></span></button> ";
    }
    return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-icon btn-primary command-edit\"  data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-target=\"#modalEdit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" data-original-title=\"Edit Sales Order\" data-placement=\"top\"><span class=\"zmdi zmdi-edit\"></span></button> " +
    deleteButton +
    "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-icon bg-green c-white command-so\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-original-title=\"Sales Order Details\" data-placement=\"top\"><span class=\"zmdi zmdi-receipt\"></span></button> " +
    "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-icon bg-deeporange c-white command-sorep\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-original-title=\"Accounts Receivable Report\" data-placement=\"top\"><span class=\"zmdi zmdi-chart\"></span></button>";

}
```

edit: I'll also add that you can get rid of all the quote escaping if you make the strings single quoted e.g.

```
        deleteButton = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-danger command-delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-target="#modalDelete" data-row-id="" + row.id + "" data-original-title="Delete Sales Order" data-placement="top"><span class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></span></button>';
```